# Mount a vue component to an element in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to mount a Vue component to an element that is rendered by a `v-html` directive. The parent Vue component is a table. Every table cell has richtext content (including images).

If there is an image in the richtext, I need to add an existing copyright component, that opens an overlay. So it can't be plain HTML.

The component looks as follows (simplified):

How do I do this?

```vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { onMounted, ref } from '#imports'

  const tableEl = ref<Array<HTMLTableElement>>([])
  const imageEls = ref<Array<HTMLImageElement>>([])
  
  onMounted(() => {
    const els = tableEl.value.querySelectorAll('p > img') 
    imageEls.value = Array.from(els) as Array<HTMLImageElement>

    imageEls.value.forEach((imageEl) => {
      const parent: HTMLParagraphElement = imageEl.parentElement as HTMLParagraphElement
      parent.style.position = 'relative' // Up to this point, everything works...

      // How do I add my "<CopyrightNotice/>" component here?
    })
  })
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
        <td ref="tdEls" v-for="col in row.cols" v-html="col.content" :key="col.id" />
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Rendered, it looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>
          <img src="/link/to/src.jpg" alt="a cat">
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with DOM using JS it is better idea to render something called `vnode`.
Your solution can break Vuejs reactivity / virtual DOM.

Follow documentation here: [Render Functions & JSX](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#components)
There is an example with combining HTML elements and Vuejs components.